# Real time CPU data for algorithms of different complexity classes

Tags: algorithm

Can anyone point me to some reliable resource/document where there is some authentic discussion on the time taken by algorithms of different complexity classes e.g. `O (log n), O (n), O(n log n), O(n^2), O(n^3)` etc. etc. Particularly I am interested in some document/site which can answer to the following question:

Given a machine configuration (CPU, Memory) how much time (in miliseconds/seconds) does it take to run mergesort (or binary search or some other standard algorithm) with N instances as input where N can vary from 100 to 1 million.

It would be even be better if someone can point me towards a document that can not only give me the time in miliseconds but also can give me an approximation/heuristics of the energy cost that will be incurred in Joules/KJoules if some of the above mentioned algorithm is run on a mobile device (smart phone).

Comment: This seems kind of a "wrong question". (1) the complexity class doesn't tell you what you want to know. (2) an *algorithm* doesn't have a cost in time or energy, even once you've specified `N` and the CPU and the memory. The precise implementation of the algorithm is important (which means the language used is important), and so is the quality of the compiler/interpreter (in particular optimization). I suppose what you're looking for amounts to a benchmarking site, though.

Comment: Yes. I am not fussy about an exact figure - as real world programs are hardly binary search with log n time complexity. What I want - is a heuristic, saying that this algorithm which runs in O(m^3 + L) time will take xxx miliseconds when run on this device with this configuration for N = 1000. I am very sure that this can be done.

Comment: It certainly cannot be done from the complexity, though. I can show you two algorithms that are both `O(n^3)`, one of which takes twice as long to run as the other. So the complexity bound is pretty much incidental to the actual performance data you're looking for.

Comment: That is very possible if your algorithms have different constants before them. But I am sure that the O(n^3) algorithm will take more than a O(log n) one, this is what I am interested in. I am not even fussy about O(n^3) , O(n^2) time. Just an approximate measure that says that with this complexity on this configuration is takes xxx ms/ns etc. Just an approximation. I will really be surprised even if this is also not available.

Comment: Java mobile used to be rife with this sort of thing when I was involved in it. I've used Futuremark and Anfymark, I think, and at the time the benchmark results on their websites for each handset / J2ME implementation would tell you how many triangles it was drawing per second, how many floating-point ops, how fast it sorted, etc. Whether that's useful to you depends whether the particular algorithm(s) you're interested in happen to be part of the detailed benchmark results, and whether the benchmark code reports real times or just relative scores. I've never used power benchmarks, though.

Comment: An example of an O(n) algorithm that is known to be pretty slow is the median-of-medians algorithm for finding the kth-largest number in an array of numbers. Each recursive call can only be guaranteed to shrink the "size" of the problem to 9/10ths of its original size, so up to 10 passes through the entire dataset are needed.

Comment: Another issue: how big are the elements?  Sorting bytes is probably faster than sorting 4-byte integers, but is unlikely to be 4 times faster on most CPUs.  I expect there will be some "linear ranges" where doubling the element size approximately doubles the running time (regardless of the algorithm's complexity), but that rule gets messed up by the presence of cache hierarchies, and then access patterns come into it in a big way (e.g. summing n elements is O(n) whether you do it in the usual order or in a random order, but these will take very different times for large n).

Comment: What if all the elements are just standard 32 bit integers? Can the time requirement be approximated then?

Comment: Well, as I said, the O(n) median-of-medians selection algorithm will be at least 10 times slower than another simpler algorithm that makes a single pass through the array, and another algorithm that makes a single pass in a highly random order will confound caching and take 10-1000 times longer (e.g. if memory needs to be paged in and out), so I would say: not really.

Answer (score 2):

I've put some time into doing just what you are asking. This isn't at the level of university research or real-time/production level code but it may help.

I've implemented a number of data structures and algorithms and run tests on them using sorted, unsorted, etc data.
http://github.com/phishman3579/java-algorithms-implementation

Also, you could easily get the other information yourself since all the code is open source and on the site.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Your site is indeed useful in some circumstances. However rather than the actual time on a fixed configuration - I am more interested in how the time is actually calculated? Or if I could put it this way - "Given an O(N^2) algorithm (A), the input to which is N = 100 32-bit integers, how much time in ns/ms/sec A will take while executing on a machine with a given CPU/Memory configuration?". I am interested in a rough heuristic/formulae which can answer this question (or at least give me a lower bound).